# Packet order for UDP video streaming

Tags: streaming, udp, video-streaming, vlc

I'm developing a kind of proxy for video streaming and I'm now dealing with an issue related to packets received out-of-order (without losses). This issue (maybe) is the reason why there are frequent noises in the video playback.

Do you know by chance if VLC is able to reorder packets? If so, it would mean that the reason why there are some noises in the playback is something else, if not, I should just develop an additional layer that ensure the reception with the correct order.

Thanks.

Comment: what protocol are you using for media transport? RTP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you are talking about RTP over UDP, AFAIK VLC uses live555 libraries for client-side RTSP/RTP functionality and live555 has a built in jitter buffer that should take care of re-ordering for you. I can't recall the size of the jitter buffer of hand but 100ms seems to ring a bell.

In case you didn't know: When developing media streaming applications (esp. over UDP) it is important to increase the size of the receiver buffer. If it is full and packets get dropped, which could explain your artifacts.

Also, UDP being unreliable means that you will experience artifacts if packets are lost/corrupted and you have no suitable mechanism to deal with it.